# jQuery - After clicking parent of file input and triggering click event to file input it returns 'too much recursion'

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click

I have this in my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload-wrap', function(event)
{
    $('[name="uploads[]"]').trigger('click');
});
```

but it returns 'too much recursion' error! however it doesn't for my other elements like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload-image-wrap', function(event)
{
    $(this).next('[name="image"]').trigger('click');

});
```

I have used setTimeout either to fix this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload-wrap', function(event)
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('[name="uploads[]"]').trigger('click');
    }, 0);
});
```

But now firefox shows top of the page that 'Firefox prevented this site from opening 99999999 pop-up windows' in which 99999999 is increasing by miliseconds.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `.upload-image-wrap` has the `'[name="uploads[]"]'` attribute, you might use `not()` to exclude the `'[name="uploads[]"]'` from triggering the delegated event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload-wrap:not([name="uploads[]"])', () => {
  $('[name="uploads[]"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Another option would be to check if the event was triggered by a human:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upload-wrap', (e) => {
  if (e.originalEvent !== undefined) $('[name="uploads[]"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Bingo :) Could you please tell me what delegated event is?

Comment: Your listener there is bound to the document, as you can see by the `$(document).on`, but it triggers only when a certain type of child is clicked. This is in comparison to a standard event listener, which, when bound to an element, runs when an event is triggered on that element itself. Eg `$('upload-wrap').on('click', ...` would add the listener to each `upload-wrap`, rather than to the `document`.